# $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q}< \infty \implies \left\| \|\chi_{n+(-1/2, 1/2]} \widehat{f}\|_{L^p_{\xi}} \right\|_{\ell^q_n}<\infty $

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis

Suppose that  support of $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is compact set $K\subset \mathbb R.$ Assume that $ \int_{\mathbb R} |\widehat{f}|^q d\xi <\infty.$ ($\widehat{\cdot}$ denote the Fourier transform).

> Question: Can we say $ \left\| \|\chi_{n+(-1/2, 1/2]} \widehat{f}\|_{L^p_{\xi}} \right\|_{\ell^q_n}<\infty$? (Here $1\leq p, q \le \infty$ and $p\neq q$)

Note: For $p=q$ it is just correct.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is true for all values of $p\in[1,\infty]$. By Hölder, it will suffice to consider the case $p=\infty$; essentially, this will follow from local constancy/reverse Hölder. With the choice $p=\infty$, we may assume that $q<\infty$.

By enlarging $K$, we may as well take $K=[-N,N]$ for some $N>2$. Let $\eta$ be such that $\eta\equiv 1$ on $K$ and $\hat{\eta}$ is supported in $[-\frac{2}{N},\frac{2}{N}]$, $\eta\geq 0$, and such that $\int\eta\lesssim N$.

Then, for each $n$ and $\xi\in[n-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2}]$, $\hat{f}(\xi)=\hat{f}*\hat{\eta}(\xi)$, so

$$|\hat{f}(\xi)|\leq\int_{-2/N}^{2/N}|\hat{f}(\xi-\omega)||\hat{\eta}(\omega)|d\omega\lesssim N\int_{-2/N}^{2/N}|\hat{f}(\xi-\omega)|d\omega.$$

Consequently,

$$\max_{\xi\in[n-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2}]}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\lesssim N\int_{n-\frac{3}{2}}^{n+\frac{3}{2}}|\hat{f}(\omega)|d\omega\lesssim N(\int_{n-\frac{3}{2}}^{n+\frac{3}{2}}|\hat{f}(\omega)|^qd\omega)^{1/q},$$

so that

$$\Big\|\|\chi_{n+(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]}\hat{f}\|_{L_\xi^\infty}\Big\|_{\ell_n^q}\lesssim N\Big\|\|\chi_{n+(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]}\hat{f}\|_{L_\xi^q}\Big\|_{\ell_n^q}<+\infty$$

as claimed.

Comment: @BJ: thanks. but it seems some typo in the last inequality  you wrote? Or I could not see the main point. Please can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Analyst the last inequality is just using the previous display, up to an extra factor of $3$ or so; the previous display was triple-counting the intervals $[n-1/2,n+1/2]$.

Comment: Many thanks. Please can you explain  how to choose $\eta$? Any reference or sketch also should be fine... Thanks

Comment: I believe the standard trick is to construct $\eta$ as an infinite convolution. If we take $N=1$, then we might get $\eta$ by taking a convolution of the form $\chi_2*(*_{n=1}^\infty\chi_{\frac{1}{100n^2}})$, where we write $\chi_r(x)=\frac{1}{2r}1_{[-2r,2r]}(x)$. We can rescale to get $\eta$ for general $N$.

Comment: It seems it is impossible to choose such $\eta$? Please this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446644/how-to-choose-some-h-so-its-fourier-transform-supported-in-some-set

Comment: Or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Noam is correct that $\eta$ can't be identically equal to 1 on an interval and have $\hat{\eta}$ with compact support, so I have over-specified $\eta$ a bit here (indeed, the construction I suggested in the previous comment only obtains $|\hat{\eta}|(\xi)\lesssim e^{-|N\xi|^c}$ for some $0<c<1$, which happens to be suitable for something unrelated I was doing). The essence of the above argument is standard, though; I can suggest a reformulation later. The identity $\hat{f}=\hat{f}*\hat{\eta}$ should be replaced by something else.